# Which type of microphone is best equipped to capture eating sounds?

Tags: microphone, recording

I am wondering which type of microphone this girl used to make her videos.

I tried condensor hypercardioid but it still doesn't sound as clear and loud.

Comment: cardioid condensor fine for fish or poultry, M-S with a condensor and ribbon combo is best for red meat and roast veggies, (depending on season) country breakfast, etc.  desserts can be tricky, i usually use a pair of 421s in X-Y configuration with a high gain preamp and hope for the best.

Comment: I edited this question so it's requesting fatual info rather than opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

Cardioid condensor which is most likely positioned just out of frame.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the best mics to capture very localized sounds are the so-called "shotgun mics", condenser microphones with a Super-Cardioid polar pattern, like the Rode NTG-2.